# Symfony command calls other commands and waits for confirmation

Tags: symfony, docker, gitlab-ci, symfony-console, doctrine-migrations

I have setup a meta command like described here https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/console/calling_commands.html

It first deletes the database, then runs a migration from scratch, and finally initializes my data.

I am facing this problem since I recently  switched from creating the schema via `doctrine:schema:create` to `doctrine:migrations:migrate`

```
class ResetDatabaseCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand {

   protected function configure()
    {
        $this
        ->setName('app:resetDb')
        ->setDescription('Reset database')
        ->setHelp('Resets the database (only for testing)');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $command = $this->getApplication()->find('doctrine:schema:drop');
        $dropInput = new ArrayInput([
            'command' => 'doctrine:schema:drop',
            '--full-database'  => true,
            '--force'  => true,]);
        $returnCode = $command->run($dropInput, $output);


        $command = $this->getApplication()->find('doctrine:migrations:migrate');
        $migrateInput = new ArrayInput([
            'command' => 'doctrine:migrations:migrate',
            '--no-interaction' => true
        ]);
        $migrateInput->setInteractive(false);
        $returnCode = $command->run($migrateInput, $output);


        $command = $this->getApplication()->find('app:initialize');
        $initInput = new ArrayInput(['command' => 'app:initialize']);
        $returnCode = $command->run($initInput, $output);
        $output->writeln('done.');
    }
}
```

ok, this does work - SOMETIMES.
When I execute this locally it works.

But I am using all this inside docker containers and a Gitlab CI toolchain.

To this end I have a shell script `init.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x # <- does not make a difference
php bin/console app:resetDb --env=prod --no-interaction
```

which  I execute in the setup phase of my Gitlab-CI test action (after the container is running:

```
docker exec php_container bash init.sh
```

The output then drives me crazy:

```
Dropping database schema...

 [OK] Database schema dropped successfully!                                     


                    Application Migrations                    


WARNING! You are about to execute a database migration that could result in schema changes and data loss. Are you sure you wish to continue? (y/n)ERROR: Job failed: execution took longer than 1h0m0s seconds
```

It means that the first command is executed as it should (drop database), but the second one waits for the "user" to type "y" as confirmation.

Note that I supplied BOTH `--no-interaction` as well as `$migrateInput->setInteractive(false);`.

The weird thing is that this command does work well locally, but not as soon as the Gitlab-CI is running it! *Edit:* even locally, I am running a php docker container. If I execute here on my mac `docker exec php_container bash init.sh` the script runs correctly!

I am using a local gitlab-ci-runner container on a docker host (I works fine since over a year).

Edit:
I also tested to put the 3 commands into the `init.sh`, with same result. The second script waits for confirmation when executed from gitlab-ci.

Next, I put the three commands into the `gitlab-ci.yml` directly:

```
test1:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose_deploy.yml up -d
    - docker exec php_1 php bin/console doctrine:schema:drop  --env=prod --full-database --force
    - docker exec php_1 php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction --env=prod
    - docker exec php_1 php bin/console app:initialize --env=prod
    - docker exec php_1 bash docker/php-fpm/initialization.sh # this is the old line that included the 3 previous commands until now
    - docker exec php_1 ./vendor/bin/simple-phpunit
```

AND THIS DOES WORK!!! So it seems the bash execution ist somehow wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by your own gitlab-ci runner ? You could launch all the sub commands inside your `.sh` script to avoid one more level of complexity, at least for test purpose

Comment: I have a computer here running a gitlab-runner inside a docker container. And Yes, this is exactly what I did just now, see my edited question.

Comment: This isn't a problem if you are using the official gitlab runner. I can't figure out why exactly your previous solution isn't working. Did you try to remove `'--no-interaction' => true` ?

Comment: I am of course using the official gitlab runner docker image.